# Date and Time Difference in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, date-arithmetic

In Oracle SQL I have merged 4  columns (ex of column names: `a_d`, `a_t`, `d_d`,`d_t`) into 2 columns (ex of names: `a_d_t` and `d_d_t`) that are each of the format: `YYYY-MMM-DD HH24:MI`. I am trying to find how much time passed (days and hours), for each observation, between `a_d_t` (the starting time) and `d_d_t` (the ending time).

I have tried `d_d_t - a_d_t` and `to_date(d_d_t)-to_date(a_d_t)`, but I got back the following for each:  `invalid identifier`.

---

For reference the code that I used (which worked), to merge the columns is:

```
to_char(to_date
( to_char (a_d,'YYYYMMDD')
    || a_t,
 'YYYYMMDDHH24MI'
   ), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
```

Comment: I think they are date, the code I used to create the 2 merged columns is above.

Comment: You have to be more precise than that - if you did in the code what you did in the post, no wonder it's not working. In the post you said you had column names a_d, a_t but in the code you have a_dt and a_time_text. If what you are saying is mostly true, then the d_d_t and a_d_t are dates already, d_d_t - a_d_t should work, it would not return "invalid identifier". That is the correct way to find the time difference (in days).

Comment: @mathguy edited code above to better match what i did.

Comment: You talk about "format" of a_d_t and d_d_t. but if you created them with `to_date()` as you show in the code, they don't have any format, they are date data type. (They are saved internally in the database in a different internal format, independent of any TEXT format that may be used to display the values on your screen). Are you able to display the values of a_d_t and d_d_t, without trying to compute the difference?

Comment: @mathguy I accidentally left out a piece--now above is what i have in my code

Comment: OK, so now you show your output a_d_t and d_d_t is not dates, but strings. I will write an answer for your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs are strings, so you must convert them to dates. But it is not sufficient to say to_date, you must also give proper format models.

```
select to_date(d_d_t, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') - to_date(a_d_t, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi') 
from   < ... >
```

will give you the difference in days. Multiply by 24, you will get it in hours.

Comment: K i tried that in the same query that I create the `a_d_t` and `d_d_t` in, but it doesn't recognize them as identifiers. What do i need to do to fix that?

Comment: Are you writing a query, and trying to get d_d_t, a_d_t and their difference, all at the same time? Or do you just need the difference? Of course you will get "invalid identifier" if you try to use the aliases in the same query where you create them for the first time, that's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Considering your inputs d_d_t, a_dare string in format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi and nls_date_format is different from it, you can try to use following query and see, if it works.

To find the duration between two date, you have to convert your date string to the date format.

```
select col_a, col_b, to_date(col_a,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')- to_date(col_b,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')duration
from x_datedur
```

replace `col_a` with ending time, `col_b` with starting time and `x_datedur` with your tablename.